# how to eliminate an item in a select box based upon how many times it occurs in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a database (db_exams) with a table called db_dates. Here timeslots are stored together with a number.

1. db_date stores the timeslots
2. db_count stores a number (the number of times the specific timeslot can be used)

the timeslots are then printed in a html form with a select box.

people can then fill in the form to book a timeslot (stored in db_booking).
now when a certain timeslot is booked full (based upon db_count and counted in db_booking) i want it to be hidden from the select.

```
        <form>
        
            <div><label for="fname">name:</label></div>
            <div><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"></div>
            
            <div><label for="email">E-mail:</label></div>
            <div><input type="email" id="email" name="email"></div>            
        
          <div><label for="Ploeg">Select timeslot:</label></div>
          <div><select>
            <option disabled selected>select timeslot</option>
            <?php
                include "config.php";  // Using database connection file here
                $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT date From dates");  // Use select query here 
        
                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                {
                    echo "<option value='". $data['date'] ."'>" .$data['date'] ."</option>";  // displaying data in option menu
                }

            ?> 

          </select></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Put an if statement around the <option> don't echo if count is full.